# SearchCriteria in White - Can't Find Name in Current Context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ui-automation, white-framework

I'm just beginning to use White for some test automation.  Pretty much every basic example shows use of SearchCriteria calls, e.g.:

```
Tab myTab = window.Get<Tab>(SearchCriteria.ByText("foo"));
```

I have the following included:

```
using TestStack.White;
using TestStack.White.UIItems;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.TabItems;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.WPFUIItems;
using TestStack.White.WindowsAPI;

using Xunit;
```

What am I missing?  Other calls seem to be working just fine, but SearchCriteria doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

`using TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders`

Comment: Good grief - I swear that was one of the first things I tried.  Thanks!